# For loop variable doesn't work in an if condition in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am first taking a specific brand of a car from one view and passing it onto the other view so that the user can then choose the model of the car.

My views.py...

```
def driver_dashboard_trip_brand (request, brand):
    brands = VehicleBrand.objects.all()
    context = {
        "brands":brands,
        "chosen_brand":brand
    }
    return render (request, "app/driver_dashboard.html", context)
```

My driver_dashboard.html...

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="brand" name="brand" onchange="submitBrand(event)">
        <option value="">Choose a brand</option>
        {% for brand in brands %}
            {% if brand == chosen_brand %}
                <option value="{{brand}}" selected>{{brand}}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{{brand}}">{{brand}}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

But then I realised that the `brand` variable doesn't get recognized in the if condition.

However, if I add something like this `{% if chosen_brand == 'BMW' %}` it works perfectly fine, but DOES NOT work if I do something like `{% if brand == 'BMW' %}`. Is there anything that I am missing out on?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `brand` is an object, and you are comparing with the string. So, make sure you compare by property which should be string.

```
        {% for brand in brands %}
            {% if brand.name == chosen_brand %}
                {{brand}}
            {% else %}
                {{brand}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

*Note:- I am using brand.name just as an example, you might have other property name like: model_name or sthg similar.

Also, you may ask that `{{brand}}` simply gives the vehicle name, why can't we compare. Answer is, `__str__` method which is used just to give string representation of an object.

Ref: [`__str__`](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-str-method-in-python)

Comment: Yesss it works perfectly fine, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things wrong here.

```
def driver_dashboard_trip_brand (request, brand):
    brands = VehicleBrand.objects.all()
    context = {
        "brands":brands,
        "chosen_brand":brand
    }
```

Here, in the brands list you get a queryset (similar to a list) of `VehicleBrand` objects. But, in the `chosen_brand` you are passing a `string` which you get from the request path parameter. This is the reason why your if condition is not working in the Django template. The easiest solution would be to

1. in `chosen_brand` pass the `VehicleBrand` object by fetching it using the `brand` using a `VehicleBrand.objects.get()` or `VehicleBrand.objects.filter().first()` query.
2. Pass the list of names in the `brands` key of the context.

Comment: Hey, your method is not wrong, however by having another query you would be reducing the performance of the website